# Error composing functions in redux after updating to the latest version of react and material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux, material-ui

My app was working well until I updated my **material ui** and **react** packages and suddenly I started getting the following error

```
 src/App.tsx 
 (156,45): Type '{}' does not satisfy the constraint ComponentType<never>.
 Type '{}' is not assignable to type StatelessComponent<never>.
```

The line 156 of my App.tsx is as I show below:

```
export default (withRoot(withStyles(styles)<{}>(connect(mapStateToProps)(withWidth()(App)))));
```

These are the version of the packages I have installed:

```
"@material-ui/core": "^3.2.1",
"@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.1",
"react": "16.5.2", 
"react-dom": "16.5.2",
```

I think the problem is with my custom `withRoot` function, or also `withStyle`, but I don't know what type is expecting now and why wasn't throwing the error before updating the libraries. I already deleted node_modules folder and reinstalled all the packages to check if maybe I missed something with the update

This is how I define my `Props` and `State` types:

```
const styles = (theme: Theme) => createStyles({...});
export namespace App {
    export interface Props extends RouteComponentProps<void>, WithStyles<typeof styles>, WithWidth {
        layout: Layout;
        history: any;
    }

    export interface State {
        mobileOpen: boolean;
    }
}

class App extends React.Component<App.Props, App.State> {
...
}
```

This is `withRoot` function:

```
function withRoot(Component: React.ComponentType) {
  function WithRoot() {
    // MuiThemeProvider makes the theme available down the React tree
    // thanks to React context.
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        {/* Reboot kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
        <CssBaseline />
        <Component {...props} />
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }

  return WithRoot;
}
```

Maybe this can help to replicate the problem, I started my project using most of ideas of this [GitHub](https://github.com/innFactory/create-react-app-material-typescript-redux) project.

Comment: Have you tried just not specifying a type? i.e. `withStyles(styles)(connect...)`

Comment: Yes, and it thrown a different error:`Type 'Props' does not satisfy the constraint 'ComponentType<never>'.
  Type 'Props' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<never>'.`

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the error, likely because I'm missing your `mapStateToProps` function.  While people may sometimes be able to spot a problem without actually compiling your code, it's always a good idea to make sure the code in your question is sufficient for people to reproduce the problem if they need to.

Comment: Yes, I know that it's difficult to reproduce without the original code, but this is a big project, it's kind a difficult to reduce the code to a test project to replicate the problem, I was hoping that someone would have seen this error before ;). If you want I can share the `mapStateToProps`, but I don't think it would help, it's pretty standard, I just map a field from the `ApplicationState`

Comment: @MattMcCutchen, I added at the end of my post a GitHub repository that could help to reproduce the error, the App.tsx has the same `export` line

Comment: I tried the repository and it doesn't give me an error.  It's up to you if you want to make the test project or wait in the hope that someone else will be able to guess what's wrong (I wouldn't count on it).

Comment: Your `withRoot` is accepting a component with no props (`React.ComponentType` := `React.ComponentType<{}>`) and then you're passing some `props` that are not defined in the code you posted. Also `withStyles(styles)<{}>` is wrong. `withStyles` takes a `ComponentType` as its generic argument not props.